# Exchange Online - List-Unsubscribe

Tags: exchange, spam, microsoft-office-365, exchangeonline

I am trying to achieve having List-Unsubscribe header functionality for our marketing emails that are being sent using Distribution list. 3rd party mailing is a no-go.

I have opened a case with M365 Support, and together with the support guy we were able to find out how to add the header to the email using the Mail Flow rules.

Shortly, we have added the following and it is visible in the email headers if you inspect it.
`List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:whatever@contonso.com>`
`List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click`

But still if I send the email to my gmail email account, it does not show me the button to unsubscribe anywhere, like if the header is there, but does not do anything.

Also [this mail checker](https://www.mail-tester.com/) says that the headers are not present, even tho they are... So I must be missing something.

I am kinda desperate now, any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do only send the email to your gmail email account, it does not show you the button to unsubscribe? In other words, does this work well when sent to other accounts that are not gmail accounts?

If so, you may be better to ask gmail supporter, and they will give you some suggestions.

In addition, I found an article about your issue may be helpful to you. [List Unsubscribe: Give Your Subscribers the Freedom to Leave](https://www.sparkpost.com/blog/list-unsubscribe-give-subscribers-freedom-leave/)

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply, well if you would read my question again, you would see that the mail checker does not recognise the header, and therefore the gmail does not too. It does not work even at outlook.com, I must be missing something, but I have those 2 headers injected as you can see in my question again. :-( I've seen this and every other articles that google comes up with :-/